# Get the (ToolStrip) parent of a ToolStripDropDownMenu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripdropdown

I am writing a custom `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`

Take for example, the following override:

```
protected override void OnRenderImageMargin(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ToolStrip is MenuStrip)
    {
        // It never is. It's always ToolStripDropDownMenu
    }
}
```

I guess that `OnRenderImageMargin` is called by the drop down menu since this is what will be rendered, however I want to get the parent `ToolStrip`/`MenuStrip`/`StatusStrip` that caused the `OnRenderImageMargin` call.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `ToolStripDropDownMenu.Parent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the `e.ToolStrip.Parent` property would be the key, but it's always `null`.

One option is to create a constructor in your `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`, and pass in a reference to the control.

```
class CustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    // All those controls derive from ToolStrip so we can use the base class here
    private ToolStrip ts;

    public CustomRenderer(ToolStrip ts)
    {
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    protected override void OnRenderImageMargin(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ts is MenuStrip)  
        {
        }
        else if (ts is StatusStrip)
        {
        }
        else  // ts is ToolStrip
        {
        }
    }
```

Then pass a reference in when you instantiate it:

```
toolStrip1.Renderer = new CustomRenderer(toolStrip1);

statusStrip1.Renderer = new CustomRenderer(statusStrip1);
```

---

An alternative option, modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255536/301857).

Forget the ctor and test the `Owner` repeatedly until you get the correct parent control:

```
protected override void OnRenderImageMargin(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStrip owner = e.ToolStrip;
    while (owner is ToolStripDropDownMenu)
        owner = (owner as ToolStripDropDownMenu).OwnerItem.Owner;

    if (ts is MenuStrip)  
    {
    }
    else if (ts is StatusStrip)
    {
    }
    else  // ts is ToolStrip
    {
    }      
}
```